# Deleting objects from REST API

Tags: ios, realm

I currently have an api call that gives me an array of featured series for a video streaming app. If one of these series gets deleted it seems realm won't delete the object if it is gone from the JSON REST response. Core Data does it so is there something I am missing with realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check your REST API you will need to delete any objects that no longer exist. A way to do this is to check what is in Realm against the primary keys you get from your REST api. If it doesn't exist, delete that object.

This isn't something that Realm does automatically since it has no way of knowing what has been deleted on your server.